# How to do a generic sort in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, c#-2.0

I have this wonderful assignment in .NET 2.0 (I miss LINQ - A LOT), where I have a list of objects. I get these objects from an API, so I cannot add any interfaces.

I need to sort them on stuff like:

- A-Z on the title
- Z-A on the title
- Newest on some date
- Oldest on some date
- A-Z on some other text string

So, while I normally would laugh and say .OrderBy(c=>c.MyTitle) , I am in doubt how you would normally do that.

I remember in my ancient days where I used the .Sort() method, but as far as I remember, you had to implement the IComparable interface, which is not possible here.

Speed is not relevant, as we're working with less than 100 items and it happens on a Page_Load event (web forms).

What do you suggest I do? Make some custom sorting algorithm (maybe even something as bad as InsertionSort)? How did people do this back in the days?

Comment: Port mono Linq code into your project and add the NET_2_0 preprocessor definition. There you have Linq in.NET 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following two overloads:

1. [overload that takes an `Comparison<T>`, which basically is a `Func<T, T, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [overload that takes an `IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx);

Using the first overload, sorting by the title ascending could look like this (borrowed from [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
list.Sort(CompareTitle);

public int CompareTitle(YourItem x, YourItem y)
{
    if (x == null)
    {
        if (y == null)
        {
            // If x is null and y is null, they're
            // equal. 
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // If x is null and y is not null, y
            // is greater. 
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If x is not null...
        //
        if (y == null)
            // ...and y is null, x is greater.
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.Title.CompareTo(y.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists still had a [`Sort method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/234b841s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) back in 2.0, which takes an [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which *also* still existed back in 2.0. (Unless by "not possible here" you mean there's another reason you can't do it, in which case, my apologies!)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can use sort with a custom delegate for comparison as answered [sort list of struct of different types in net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477106/sort-list-of-struct-of-different-types-in-net-2-0)